# output result is blank and turns out parameter is not defined?

Tags: javascript, debugging

here is the code of the Javascript that i made[image]

When i run the code the output result is blank and i went to the console and the error code is
[image]

i try to find the fix by changing the variable but nothing seems fix this problem idk it just a parameter , i should have to use let "Variable" right ? anyone can help Thanks.

Comment: where is searchValue declared and initialized? first, you have to declare variable!

Comment: wait, i  found the solution already imma post on my own question i think i found it. it seems my "Penemuan" is a function Iscontain and i should put the parameter array and penyarian  because in the searchValue it just a function and when i want to declare my function  i should use the array and the "penyarian" Nevermind and thanks for the respond it just trigger my idea haha.

Comment: Great, sometimes it happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my answers after Think hard enough it seem the code where `const penemuan = Iscontain(array,searchValue)` it is wrong the searchValue i should make it to Penyarian cuz the name of the variable is penyarian and the variable searchValue is used on the Function so it should be `Iscontain(array,penyarian)` than it will work.